# Vertical lines on my laptop

Tags: lcd

When connect to external monitor, it displays normally, but when I start laptop, from the beginning it displays these lines always.

[image: Vertical lines on screen]

Comment: What have you got taped to the screen? If that's more than maybe 0.5mm thick, that could have been responsible for cracking the display when you closed the lid.

Comment: Its new lcd panel, testing before screw

Comment: If you caused the damage you may be out of luck. If you did not cause the damage, it may be returnable.

Comment: My previous panel also doesnt show,so the problem with new panel and old panel,not showing similar but both display faulty

Comment: If you just changed the screen, that might just be a badly-connected ribbon cable. It's always smartest to change the cable before suspecting the display panel itself.

Comment: When i connected first,it was normal 5-10 seconds,them became like this

Comment: If it does it on 2 displays, the chances increase that it's the cable.

Comment: This type of corruption is caused by faulty cables or connections, where some of the data lines are not connected properly. It can also be internal to the screen, where delicate flexible flat cables are used.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating the Video driver and the BIOS.

More than likely, however, there is a problem with the display and it needs to be replaced (broken or otherwise damaged, or display cable (ribbon cable).

Windows 11 (screen shot) so the computer may be new enough to be under warranty. Check this.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this lcd just nee one to fix problem.i tested with new lcd panel on photo,will try to update bios ,the screen same on bios screen too

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you can put a screenshot up rather than a external photo? will help rule out a cracked display. but my laptop did the same after i dropped it, turned out the LCD panel was cracked under the bezel causing a similar issue.

If its displaying normally when connected to a external display, sounds like a broken panel to me unfortunately.

Comment: This is a new panel to test,i forgot to tell when i connected new panel,it displayed perfect 5-10 seconds,then became like this

Answer (score 0):

Power down and reboot to confirm that this isn't a very unlikely issue with video ram or software corruption. Assuming the issue remains this is undoubtedly a screen issue (you could also boot into the BIOS to be sure it's not software).

The most likely problem is that the thin ribbon cable connecting the screen to the motherboard is damaged or loose.

It's also possible that the LCD itself is broken but that is usually accompanied by some signs of physical stress in the form of cracks on the edge of the display or in the plastic around it.

Comment: I forgot to tell, when i connected new panel,it showed 5-10 seconds perfect,later became like this